# Novice - routing between two interfaces

Tags: networking

I am trying to setup two interfaces on Ubuntu 14.04LTS server and have read many similar threads on this forum but nothing seems to work for me (or I don’t fully understand it). I am not sure if I need bridging, port forwarding or static routes or what?

The setup below works OK so far. I can serve web pages on both main interfaces. These main interfaces may be setup with a static address and DHCP server of may be DHCP clients.
Also, there is an app running on the server that access a Wi-Fi module over Ethernet SNMP. This has a fixed IP of 192.168.168.1 and this works OK over the alias interface em1:1.

My question is how do I change the setup so that I can access the Wi-Fi module on 192.168.168.1 from the p3p1 interface?

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.130.59.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p3p1
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
10.130.59.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p3p1
192.168.168.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
```

I have forwarding enabled in /etc/sysctl.conf: 
  net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

```
/etc/network/interfaces:
# loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# primary network interface - ethernet I/F
auto p3p1
allow-hotplug p3p1
iface p3p1 inet dhcp

# second network interface - wifi I/F
auto em1
allow-hotplug em1
iface em1 inet static
  address 10.0.2.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

# virtual network interface - wifi I/F for 192.168.x.x connections
auto em1:1
allow-hotplug em1:1
iface em1:1 inet static
  address 192.168.168.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Not really clear what you want to do. Is there any computer in p3p1 attached network who should be able to connect to some computer in em1:1? And what is that virtual network for? Please give some example/hints.

Comment: PC with static address 192.168.168.10 is connected to p3p1. It needs to connect to WiFi setup web pages on 192.168.168.1

Comment: This won't work. First, the computer  in p3p1 network has to have an address in 10.130.59.0 with this setup, to reach your "router". Or you add virtual network interface to device p3p1 with IP address in 192.168.168.5 (_not_ to em1) and define the default gateway to be 192.168.168.5 in 192.168.168.10.

Comment: I would like to connect a PC with static address 192.168.168.10 to p3p1 so the WiFi can be set up manually. The virtual network em1:1 is how I managed to get the application running on the server to talk to the WiFi to set it up programmably using SNMP. The whole thing is going to be potted and only p3p1 Ethernet will be available to the outside world

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize your configuration:

There is a network `N1` (`10.130.59.0/24`) with default gateway `DG` (`10.130.59.1`).

There is a network `N2` (`10.0.2.0/24`) with no world access (no default gateway).

There is a server `S1` attached to both networks: To `N1` via `p3p1` (DHCP address, something like `10.130.59.x`) and to `N2` via `em1` (static address `10.0.2.1`).

You have a WLAN AP/router `AP` connected to `N2` with static IP address `192.168.168.1` for unknown reason (why not address in range `10.0.2.0/24`?).

You have a PC `PC` connected to `N1` with static address `192.168.168.10` for unknown reason (why not address in range `10.130.59.0/24`?).

You created a virtual network `VN` at `em1.1`on`S1`with address range `192.168.168.0/24`. So from `S1` (`192.168.168.5`) you are able to reach `AP`, as both are on the same network `VN`.

Now you want to route traffic from `PC` via `S1` to `AP`. But as `VN`is already bound to `em1:1`, you cannot create a route to `PC` in `N1`. There is  just one possible solution, if you cannot change the IP address of `AP`: Give `PC` an address in `N1` (`10.130.59.x`) and set a static route on `PC` to `192.168.168.0`via the IP address of `S1` (DHCP, therefore maybe different next time).

If you cannot change the IP Address of `PC`, you need to split your`VN`into two parts, one in `N1` and one in `N2` with different netmasks. But this would only help ifyou could modify the netmask of `AP`, and ifyou can do that, you also could change the address of `AP`... And why not plug `PC`in `N2`?

Comment: You have summed it up very well, thanks. PC address was just an example, it can be anything. AP address is fixed (at least when AP is reset to factory settings it will be fixed).N1 and N2 addresses can be set to anything (at least when we need to set up AP). I need to connect PC to AP to do some initial setup/firmware upgrade. Then everything can be put back into production mode. I will give your suggestion a try, thanks.

Comment: Just for further background, the unit is an embedded server that will be used to control an oil drilling platform. As this need to be intrinsically safe the whole thing will be potted. Only N1 and WiFi is available to the outside world. In fact N2 is just a circuit board trace to a WiFi router SOC. Good fun eh?